Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined in Flask
I'm trying to use flask_ckeditor in my flask project. I followed the doc but keep getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined (in browser console).
Here is my form:
class AdminUserCreateCKForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    pwdhash = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    admin = BooleanField('Admin')
    content = CKEditorField('Content')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

My template:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div style="padding-top: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
    <form action="{{ url_for('auth.admin.user_create_ck') }}" method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ render_field(form.username) }}
        {{ render_field(form.email) }}
        {{ render_field(form.pwdhash) }}
        {{ render_field(form.admin) }}
        {{ form.content() }}
        {{ render_field(form.submit) }}
    </form>
    {{ ckeditor.load(custom_url=url_for('static', filename='ckeditor/ckeditor.js')) }}
    {{ ckeditor.config(name='content') }}
</div>
{% endblock %}

Trying to serve ckeditor.js from local, so here is my application factory:
# ...some stuff
ckeditor = CKEditor()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    app.config['CKEDITOR_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True
# the rest of the stuff...

Every other field in the form, render without issue. But for 'content' i only get a simple textarea.
Did try to load ckeditor in my base.html with a script tag. Did  not work.
(bootstrap loads fine. So i think my static folder is accessed properly.)

I was able to fix the problem by replacing the ckeditor.js file with the entire version 4 (ready-to-use) standard package.
Note: LTS does not work.

I have created your application with flask-ckeditor==0.5.1 and it's working fine. I used {{ ckeditor.load() }} and it's rendering the url as https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@BcK May i ask if you also tried serving from local instead of CDN?

@ark948 no I haven't tried serving from local. But you can easily download the file from the cdn, replace your already existing one if needed, and serve it from your local.
